# Is iterator supported by Processing?

Tags: java, iterator, processing

I hope to use a hashmap in Processing and I hope to use an iterator to traverse all the entries in the hashmap. However, when I hope to use iterator, I am told that "Cannnot find a class or type named Iterator". Part of the code are shown below.

```
Iterator i = nodeTable.entrySet().iterator();  // Get an iterator
while (i.hasNext()) 
{
  Node nodeDisplay = (Node)i.next();
  nodeDisplay.drawSelf();
}
```

From the processing website http://processing.org/reference/HashMap.html I know that iterator can be used to traverse hashmap. Howevre, I cannot find more information about iterator. I am wondering whether iterator is supported in Processing? Or should I import some libraries so that I would be able to use them?

Comment: Did you `import java.util.Iterator;`?

Comment: Also, use generics to make your code type-safe.

Comment: Thank you! I did not import it. I just tried to import java.util.Iterator, but I was told that i.next() cannot be cast to the class Node, which is a self defined class. @A--C

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet , I tried to use "Iterator<Node> i" but I am still faced with ClassCastException.

Comment: Then post the actual code, including the part which creates and populates the collection, and the complete stack trace of the exception. If you have a ClassCastException with generic types, you're using them wrong, and not using them will only make things worse.

Comment: I have got the problem solved after using generic types. Thank you a lot for your kind help! @JBNizet

Answer (score 2):

So long as I have got the problem solved, I will put part of my code here in case someone else may come across this. Thank you again for your kind help.

```
import java.util.Iterator;  // Import the class of Iterator
// Class definition and the setup() function are omitted for simplicity

// The iterator is used here
HashMap<String, Node> nodeTable = new HashMap<String, Node>();
void draw(){
    // Part of this function is omitted
    Iterator<Node> i = nodeTable.values().iterator();
    // Here I use the iterator to get the nodes stored the hashtable and I use the function values() here. entrySet() or keySet() can also be used when necessary
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Node nodeDisplay = (Node)i.next();
        // Now you can use the node from the hashmap
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad you solved your problem, but for others coming across this, if you want to iterate on the `entrySet()`, there are two ways of doing it. The first way of doing it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> strMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        strMap.put("foo", "bar");
        strMap.put("alpha", "beta");
        for (Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = strMap.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
        {
            Entry<String, String> entry = iter.next();
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Note the imports at the top of the code, you're probably missing the one for the `Iterator`.

And the second:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> strMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        strMap.put("foo", "bar");
        strMap.put("alpha", "beta");
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : strMap.entrySet())
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

This is called a [for-each loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), and removes the need to use an `Iterator` at all and makes the code much more simple. Note that this can also be used on arrays to remove the need for an index:

```
String[] strs = {"foo", "bar"};
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str);
```